# Training tensorflow to apply contrast

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, gan

Framework I used: [pix2pix tensorflow](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow)

I am trying to train pix2pix to correct contrast on an image. However, I am getting blurred and grainy images. There is lot of black noise in the image(examples below). Is it because of the loss?

Note: I have made no change to pix2pix-tensorflow and used it as is.
The losses I see at the end of my training are:

- discriminator loss: around 0.7
- generator_loss_GAN: around 2.2
- generator_loss_L1: around 0.16

Sample outputs: (Input-Output-Target)

[image]

Another example:
[image]

Loss information from tensorboard:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Am I first of all using correctly for my usecase?
2. How can I make sure there is no loss of data in the image at all and only the light amount changes in the target picture?
3. If GAN isn't right way, can you let me know how to achieve this?